# SQLite: average of column indexed by two columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

Given the following table

```
+----+----+------+
|id1 |id2 |value |
+----+----+------+
| 1  | 2  | 10   |
| 1  | 3  | 20   |
| 1  | 4  | 30   |
| 2  | 3  | 10   |
| 2  | 4  | 40   |
| 3  | 4  | 10   |
+----+----+------+
```

I want to have avg(value) of each id, whether located the id1 or id2 column.

Thus, the output should be:

```
1,20

2,20

3,16.66

4,26.6
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `UNION ALL`:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT id, value FROM tab
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id2, value FROM tab
)
SELECT id, AVG(value) AS value
FROM cte
GROUP BY id;
```

**[DBFidde Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.16&fiddle=f37725a342202f752d4938ec023ffa4f)**

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: @user44136 you should accept this answer, not only thank.